# Getting an array back from php after Ajax POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I am sending an array I have in javascript to php using:

```
usernames = ['username1','username2']


$.ajax({
            url: "my_Url",
            type: "post",
            data: {username:usernames} ,
            success: function (response) {
               // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)     
               alert(response);
            }
        });
```

data will be sent to the php script containing what is below:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$usernames = $_POST['username'];
echo $usernames;
?>
```

The problem is I get an alert saying Array but not what is in the actual array itself. How do I get what is inside the array and put it in a variable again.

Comment: What do you want to do with that array?

Answer (score 0):

Because the data type is an array, that is what javascript will alert from the echoed PHP. Typically, you can convert the array to a string, which can be visualized in the ajax response, using `json_encode()`

```
echo json_encode($usernames);
```

and then to process the JSON on the frontend, use `JSON.parse()`. As one user has pointed out, it is useful in the backend script to set a content header before echoing the json:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

This approach is discussed in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script).

Another possibility that is useful for a numeric array such as in your code, is to simply echo the imploded array, which will convert it to a string:

```
echo implode(",", $usernames); // the ajax response will be username1,username2 here
```

Comment: You may want to add that setting `header('Content-type: application/json');` will help jquery automatically process the returned data into something javascript can directly consume.

Comment: @SuperJer is it required if you add `dataType: 'json'` to you AJAX call?

Comment: @SuperJer, it's not necessary but will edit answer to include your suggestion based on another post